# How to set many to many relationships using SSMS 18.0?

Tags: database, entity-framework

I am new in sql server and I am trying to set many to many relationships between two tables, I have found some examples using code but I do not want to use SQL code to accomplish this. I added relationships using the default sql server designer just by clicking **Relationships...**

[image: Relationships]

In the above image I cannot see options to define relationships so I am having a hard time to find it.

After importing my "database first" to Entity Framework I get the following relations:

[image]

It means they are not set to *Many-to-Many*. I am somewhat new into databases.

Comment: Many-to-Many requires a linking table, you cannot do it with a single FK constraint alone.

Comment: Thank you, I got you. You should post this as a answer soI can mark as solved.